# Sonar Violations of Unused methods in if statement

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have implemented some lines of codes as:

```
if(condition){
  Class a = new Class();
  method(a.b(), a.c());
}else{
  method(null, null);
}
```

Sonar fails on **protected b** and **protected c** as unused. Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure `condition` can ever be true?

Comment: Is it showing number of times it has been missed same as conditional statements?

Comment: @njzk yes, ofcourse. Its dependent on Backend.

Comment: @GouravSingh No

Comment: What version of SonarQube and the java analyzer are you using for your analysis?

Comment: @Michael-SonarSourceTeam I don't know about Sonar version because its running on Jenkin server, java version is 7. Is SonarQube version affects this? if yes which version should solve this problem?

Comment: @SanatPandey I was asking for the version of SonarQube, and the version of the SonarQube Java Analyzer plugin, not the required version of java of your project, which is not related to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Rule "Unused Protected Method" has been deprecated in version `4.1`, and dropped in version `4.2` of the **SonarQube Java Analyzer plugin**, due to its poor reliability (numerous false positives). We are consequently not maintaining this rule anymore.

If these issues are wrong, like you said and as it probably is, simply mark them as "False Positive" (if you are using LTS `5.6` version of SonarQube), or "Won't Fix". There is nothing to fix and SonarQube is doing a mistake.

Note that updating the Java Analyzer Plugin to version 4.2 will make the issue disappear, but only because the rule itself will disappear from available rules.

Comment: Ok, So what you said as Migrate to Sonar version 4.2 will solve the problem or I have to mark them "False Positive" and I didn't tell that these issues are wrong I want the fix of violations because in if statement I am calling the functions properly however this violations occur.

Comment: Why this violation occur please tell me and how we can overcome to this?